# I can’t find the source of my runtime error. Implemented recursion to solve a problem

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, runtime-error, depth-first-search

I’m trying to answer [this problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/839/problem/C) on code forces. [Here](https://codeforces.com/contest/839/submission/75648501) is my latest submission (I think others can be found from there).

My method:
Read inputs. The list of lists "mapp" stores the cities that are connected to the city represented by the index of the list i.e. mapp[i-1] represents the cities connected to the i’th city.
I’m using DFS method to solve the problem as per the tutorial for the problem.

When I run the test cases given in the problem the code runs fine and I get correct answers. However, when I submit the problem I always get a runtime error on test 4. I

```
n = int(input())

def hasChildren(prev, current):
    node = mapp[current-1]
    travelled = 0.0
    l1 = len(node)

    if len(node) == 1 and node[0] == prev:
        return 0.0

    for elem in node:
        if elem == prev:
            l1 -= 1.0
        else:
            travelled += (1.0+hasChildren(current, elem))

    return travelled/l1


if n == 1:
    print("%.6f" % 0.000000)
else:
    mapp = [[] for x in range(n)]

    for x in range(n-1):
        [u,v] = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
        mapp[u-1].append(v)
        mapp[v-1].append(u)
    length = hasChildren(1,1)
    print("%.6f" %length)
```

Comment: try to replicate the test locally, if possible, and check if errors appear.

Comment: I can’t see the entirety of the input, I’ve been trying to figure out what kind of input would cause an error but haven’t been successful.

Comment: [dfs] tag is not the right one here:  **"DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]"**